# Hibernate Criteria in Clause with 2 conditions in 1 Query

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

How do i acheive the following SQL Query using Hibernate Criteria Query:

```
select * from Table1 where (A,B) in (select A,B from Table2)
```

Comment: You can't. There's no support for that in Criteria, and AFAIK, not even in HQL.

Comment: we can do the same using SubQueries

Answer (score 2):

Assuming we have Criteria for Table 1 and Detached Criteria for Table 2. This below code work flawlessly:

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria(Table1.class);

DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Table2.class); 
ProjectionList projList = Projections.projectionList();
projList.add(Projections.property("column1"));
projList.add(Projections.property("column2"));
dc.setProjection(Projections.distinct(projList));

criteria.add(Subqueries.propertiesIn(new String[]{"column1","column2"}, dc));
```